# JavaScript unable to display weather

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am using a JSFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/23HQC/7/) - I have placed CSS, JavaScript, and HTML in one file, and am using WampServer to run it. There is no weather information being displayed. I double-checked everything, but cannot find the problem. Any suggestions?

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
.weatherModule {
    background:#f2f2f2;
    height:150px;
    width:250px;
    border: 1px dashed #ccc;
    padding: 1em;
}
.currentConditions {
    float: left;
}
.weatherModule {
    padding: 1em;
}

.currentIcon {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 .75em;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

displayWeather(){

$.ajax
    url: 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/36b799dc821d5836/conditions/q/PA/Horsham.json'
    dataType: 'jsonp'
    data: 'url'
    success: (data) ->
        for index, result of data
                temp = Math.round result.temp_f
                icon = result.icon_url
                weather = result.weather
                $('p.currentConditions').html "Currently  #{temp} &deg; F and #{weather}"
                $('div.currentIcon').html "<img src='#{icon}' >"

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="weatherModule">
<p class="currentConditions"></p>
<div class="currentIcon"></div>
</div>
<form>
<button type="button" onclick="displayWeather()">Display Weather</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your fiddle works for me.

Comment: `$.ajax({ [parameters] });`

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @u_mulder It's coffeescript, you leave out lots of brackets.

Comment: @Sumurai8 That's what he said: it works in jsfiddle, not on his real site.

Comment: @Barmar, it is, but does it work in `OP` wampserver?

Comment: Have you run your code through the coffeescript compiler to convert it to Javascript?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

```
crossDomain: true,
```

to your $.ajax options.

Comment: That only has an effect when making a request to the *same origin* which gets **redirected** to a different origin. There's nothing to indicate that is happening here.